# Onion Cells or Pear Cells?

Tags: cell-biology, homework, microscopy

[image: Cells under Brightfield Microscopy]

I am researching different cells under a brightfield microscope for homework and am having trouble determining whether or not these cells are Onion cells (*Allium cepa*) or pear cells (*Pyrus*) under a light microscope. I am pretty sure they are pear cells, but I just wanted to be sure!

Comment: Pear has loosely arranged spherical cells and some cells are sclereids cells. Onions cells are rectangular and almost transparent.
Honestly I'm about to vote for closing, because I don't see how this question can be important.

Comment: @MaximKuleshov No question should be closed solely because it is unimportant, but this question doesn't show any effort at in researching the question before posting. What were you expecting the difference to be? Where did you previously try to answer this question and what didn't you understand about those answers? Why are you pretty sure it's a pear cell? I think this question is close to being a very nice question.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, those are pear cells.

Onion **skin** cells (popularly in slide sets)

[image]

[source and a hommge to onion skin cells](http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/indexmag.html?http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/artnov03/wdonion.html)

Pear Cells

[image]

[source and also several other neat pictures of pear cells](http://blog.microscopeworld.com/2014/12/pear-under-microscope.html)